# Flutter: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter

I'm coding the class

> class _DashboardState extends State
> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
> late Future _summaryData;
> late Future<List> _chartData;
>
> ```
>   @override
>   initState() {
>     super.initState();
>     Future<Map> data = fetchData();
>     _summaryData= data['summaryData']; // ERROR HERE
>     _chartData= data['chartData']; // ERROR HERE
>   }
>
>   Future<Map> fetchData() async {
>     ...
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return FutureBuilder(
>       future: _summaryData,
>       builder: ...);
>   }
> ```

but I face an error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'. Try defining the operator '[]'.`.

Please tell me the reason and how to solve? thank you!

Comment: You're missing waiting for your future data.  Since you can't use await in initState, it'll have to be with a .then.  Learn about Future.then in the async documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to access summaryData and chartData from a `Future<Map>` and not a `Map`. In your `fetchData()` function, make it so that you return `Map` and not a `Future<Map>` like so:

```
Map fetchData() async {
 return await fetchDataAPICall(); /// Whatever way you are fetching the data
}
```

This should return you a `Map` within which you should be able to access your required data.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following.

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

void getData()async{
Future<Map> data = await fetchData();
    _summaryData= data['summaryData']; // ERROR FIX
    _chartData= data['chartData']; // ERROR FIX
}

  Future<Map> fetchData() async {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _summaryData,
      builder: ...);
  }
```

since await cannot be added to init method we create a separate method and mark it async to wait for the api call data.